# Only answering questions asked directly, only volunteering specific details

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I've seen several characters in different mediums do this, and I was wondering if there is a word or phrase to more easily explain it. I'm referring to when someone gives specific details about something in a way which serves their purposes and refuses to volunteer information that might be useful to who they're talking to without being directly asked, but will be absolutely truthful in their responses to direct questions. I see a lot of villains and demons do this sort of thing in a lot of stories.

Comment: Aggressive compliance?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be 'Only answering questions asked directly, not volunteering any details'? // 'It's like trying to get blood from a stone' is often used when eliciting information proves difficult.

Comment: In a legal seeing, I think this would be called *a well-prepped witness*.

Comment: That's somewhat true in a legal sense. It's not so much that eliciting information is difficult if you know the right questions to ask.

Comment: It's not really aggressive compliance since you aren't overwhelming with information, so much as only giving good answers when directly asked and giving deceptive information freely. Also although the information you volunteer without being asked is deceptive, you never outright lie.

Comment: I think KannE is the closest to what I'm talking about so far. Selective memory is similar, however it's a bit different imo. An example would be offering someone a deal where you give them certain benefits in exchange for something but you don't fully disclose the downsides. When they call you out on withholding information "you would have told them if they had asked".

Comment: [cagey](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cagey)

Comment: Lying by omission.

Comment: i don't think there is a word for this, so it is going to be very hard to get an answer

Comment: @ColinFine this is one of the tactics in "malicious compliance" I'd say, very near "working to the letter" (in which someone complies with the job description exactly as it says, not more not less)

Comment: Good question. However, this may elicit better results on a more relevant SE site as it is not entirely about the English language or its usage. If the OP were able to concretise the idea, the corresponding term could be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**terse**

> adj.  Brief and to the point; effectively concise:

As in:

> His answers were terse.

Answer (score 0):

You actually seem to be referring to two different things.

[**Selective**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selective):

> of, relating to, or characterized by selection : selecting or tending to select
>
> highly specific in activity or effect · *selective* pesticides · *selective* absorption

[**Literal**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literal):

> Taking words in their usual or most basic sense without metaphor or exaggeration.
>
> Free from exaggeration or distortion.
>
> (of a person or performance) lacking imagination; prosaic.

Answer (score 0):

Those people are just answering ***to the point***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[to the point](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+point)**
>
> expressed in a simple, clear way **without any extra information or
>   feelings**:
>   The speech was short and to the point.
>
> Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary © Farlex 2017

Answer (score 0):

I will also suggest "**stonewalling**" that carries this meaning of being a deliberate effort from the speaker to be particularly uncooperative.

[Stonewalling on Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stonewalling)

> 2: to be uncooperative, obstructive, or evasive

And if you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonewalling) there is also a section in stonewalling performed by witnesses that lists as potential stonewalling tactics by witnesses (who are sworn to say the truth) the following items:

- Not volunteering information
- Refusing to testify
- Provide misleading information
- Purposefully witholding pieces of information that might be self-incriminating